# How do I delete a folder generated by Foremost?

Tags: delete, directory

I used the Foremost tool for data recovery. It was taking too long so I decided to quit it. I closed the terminal and now it has left some folders behind and they have a lock sign on them. I want to delete them because they are occupying about 100 GB of my hard drive.  I can't delete them even by becoming root.

```
sudo -s    
rmdir recoveredforemost
```

I made that folder `recoveredforemost` to store recovered data? How do I remove these folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved it if anybody having the same problem try this

```
sudo -s                                             //become root
cd Desktop/recovered                               // go to directory for eg in my case recovered
chown username recovered
```